# Where can I find the default location for keystores created by Xamarin Android in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keystore, android-keystore

When I archive an Android app, then distribute it, I'm given the option to create a keystore. Once I create it, where does it go by default?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 15):

In Visual Studio, Xamarin lets you create the keystore when distributing. However, it doesn't make it clear where exactly it puts it.

I found it in:
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\

There are many folders in there, generally matching the names of the distribution profiles you seen when archiving Android packages in Visual Studio.

I found my keystore files in those folders.

You can also do a search in that folder for the keystore name and find it relatively quickly.

Good luck!

Comment: Its in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 3):

You can find them in C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore

You can simply click on Open Folder Below Distribute while Archive the Apk.

From there you can simply found Mono for Android in above Folders From there Go to Key store and you can find Respective Project Key store files